# Regex to Parse XML - RSS Feed

Tags: regex, parsing, xml-parsing, rss

```
<atom:link rel="self" href="http://www.independent.co.uk/"/>
<item>
<title>
Coronavirus: Why the Covid-19 economic stimulus deal will make it to Trump&apos;s desk
</title>
<link>
https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/coronavirus-economic-stimulus-deal-covid-19-trump-bill-senate-house-a9419976.html
</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[
News Analysis: When Senate tries to pass major bills, there's always one day of chaos. Monday appears to be that day.
]]>
</description>
```

For the content above i would like to extract the title, link and description
How can I formulate my regex rule to capture this?

The end goal being to dump the extracted content to a predefined sql db that i created

Comment: atom is an XML format so it would be easier to use an xml library to parse and read the RSS feed

Comment: The canonical answer to 'how can I parse HTML with regex' is https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/. It also applies to XML. That being said: if you provide information about which stack you are using, people can provide you with alternative approaches how to reach your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments most likely you should be using an XML parser and not regex, but as the format of the RSS feed is probably consistent and quite simple a regex solution might work too.

For the current example you can use:

```
<(.+)>\s*(?:<!\[CDATA\[)?\s*(.*)\s*(?:]]>)?\s*<\/\1>
```

Explanation:

- `<(.+)>` - matches opening tag, captures the name
- `\s*` - matches optional whitespace characters (new line in your example)
- `(?:<!\[CDATA\[)?` - non-capturing group for `<![CDATA[`, matched 0 or 1 times
- `\s*` - matches optional whitespace characters
- `(.*)` - capturing group that will catch any characters
- `\s*` - matches optional whitespace characters
- `(?:]]>)?` - non-capturing group for `]]>` (CDATA closing), matched 0 or 1 times
- `\s*` - matches optional whitespace characters
- `<\/\1>` - matches closing tag with same name as opening tag (backreference to 1st capture group)

```js
let input = `<title>
Coronavirus: Why the Covid-19 economic stimulus deal will make it to Trump&apos;s desk
</title>
<link>
https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/coronavirus-economic-stimulus-deal-covid-19-trump-bill-senate-house-a9419976.html
</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[
News Analysis: When Senate tries to pass major bills, there's always one day of chaos. Monday appears to be that day.
]]>
</description>`;

let regex = /<(.+)>\s*(?:<!\[CDATA\[)?\s*(.*)\s*(?:]]>)?\s*<\/\1>/g;

let result;
do {
  result = regex.exec(input);
  if (result) {
    console.log(result[1] + ": " + result[2]);
  }
} while (result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the solution